# Get date in css store in js in a js created element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning Javascript and I try to build a to do app. I input the task and the date. I want to have a list with each task and its assigned date. Can this be done with only HTML/Javascript, picking the date with a HTML?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="task">
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="in-text" />
    <input type="date" class="in-date" />
  </form>
</div>
<div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
</div>
const todoInput = document.querySelector(".in-text");
const todoDate = document.querySelector(".in-date");

document.addEventListener("keyup", addTodo);

function addTodo(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  const newTodoDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const newTodoElement = document.createElement("li");
  newTodoElement.innerText = todoInput.value;
  newTodoDiv.appendChild(newTodoElement);

  //HERE IS SOME OF WHAT I THOUGHT IT WOULD BE DONE LIKE
  const newTodoDate = document.createElement("date");//i know date can`t be used like this
  newTodoDiv.appendChild(newTodoDate);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. How this works: you post code that shows your attempt along with an exact question or 2. Otherwise generally you don't get help and people close down your question. drawings and links are fine but are not a substitute for formatted code and specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code structure from your drawing. You might need to wrap your date inside a non-breaking element like span to show your date.

On the change event of the date picker, you can update those spans. Here's a small demo of it.

```js
const datePicker = document.getElementById("date-selector");
const dateSections = document.getElementsByClassName("date");

// adding a listener to the date picker on its onchange event.
datePicker.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const d = new Date(e.target.value);
  const date = d.getDate();
  const month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = d.getFullYear();
  // this is an interpolated string, you can format it in any way you like
  const formattedString = `${date}/${month}/${year}`;

  // update all "date" sections
  for (let section of dateSections) {
    section.innerHTML = formattedString;
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="date-selector" type="date" />

<ul>
  <li> Task1 <span class="date">10/01/22</span> </li>
  <li> Task1 <span class="date">10/01/22</span> </li>
  <li> Task1 <span class="date">10/01/22</span> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. But its not doing what I want. The date picker works in a some strange way and it updates every elements date. Maybe you can understand more from my edited question and code added.

Comment: @TimoteiSatmarean, Here, I've added a similar version of the application, adjusted according to your code provided. 
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ztcyms1q/20/)